# Python creating more then one object from a single class IN the class

Tags: python, function, class, object, attributes

I would like to create 5 objects (serial number, part number, card name, card status, card type). My code takes in a file which contains some strings (Information about each card). As you can see from the code, I am creating only one object right before the for loop in the main function. I would like to create the object where it says "create the object here". The object is card, each card has a part number, serial number, name, status and type. When I run this code, it only output's the Card-Name because it is only creating one object. However, if I put them all in an array or dictionary and I output that, then it will output everything (again because it is creating one object ONLY). How can I get it to output all of these informations. I know my problem is with the way I am creating the object. I am new to python, so any help would greatly be appreciated. Also, yes I would like all of my variables to be private.

```
###############
#output:
#Card-Name:  CPM B
#Serial-Number:
#part-Number:
#Card-Status:
#Card-Type
##############

class Slot(object):
  card_sn = ""
  card_pn = ""
  card_name = ""
  card_status = ""
  card_type = ""

  def __init__(self):
    self.__card_sn = ""
    self.__card_pn = ""
    self.__card_name = ""
    self.__card_status = ""
    self.__card_type = ""

  def CPM_detail(self,input,region,subregion):
      temp = re.search(r'(\s+)Card (A|B|C|D)',input)
      if temp:
        ############
        #would like to create the object here
        ############
        self.__card_name = "CPM "+str(temp.group(2))                         
        temp = re.search(r'Memory capacity',input)
        if temp:
          self.__card_type = temp.group(1)
        temp = re.search(r'\s{10,}(\S+)\s{20,}',input)
        if temp:
          self.__card_status = str(temp.group(1))
        temp = re.search(r'(\s+)Serial number(\s+): (\S+)',input)
        if temp:
           self.__card_sn = temp.group(3)
        temp = re.search(r'(\s+)Part number(\s+): (\S+)',input)
        if temp:
           self.__card_pn = temp.group(3)

  def serial_number(self):
    return self.__card_sn
  def part_number(self):
    return self.__card_pn
  def card_name(self):
    return self.__card_name
  def card_status(self):
    return self.__card_status
  def card_type(self):
    return self.__card_type


def main():
  with open ('/home/thamer/TS_ncren202_XRS-20_20150624_12.0.R6.txt','r') as f:
    slot_cards = Slot()
    for line in f: 
      slot_cards.CPM_detail(line,region,subregion)
      serialNumber = slot_cards.serial_number()
      partNumber = slot_cards.part_number()
      cardName = slot_cards.card_name()
      cardStatus = slot_cards.card_status()
      cardType = slot_cards.card_type()
      print "Card-Name: ",cardName
      print "Serial#: ",serialNumber
      print "part#: ",partNumber
      print "Card-Status: ",cardStatus
      print "Card-Type ",cardType 


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Those 5 class attributes serve no purpose; they don't "declare" the instance variables as you seem to be expecting.

Comment: Then how do I do that? @chepner

Comment: Since I do not understand instancing very much

Comment: You don't declare instance variables at all in Python; you simply assign values to them, essentially creating them on demand. By convention, you create and initialize them in `__init__`.

Comment: Can you show me in the code how can I fix this. @chepner